# Find the min in a rotated array. Understanding the implementation

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

There is a rotated array, and we need to find its min element in log n time. I found several solutions [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2014/02/leetcode-find-minimum-in-rotated-sorted-array/) and can't understand one of them:

```
public int findMin(int[] nums) {
    if(nums==null || nums.length==0)
        return -1;

    int i=0; 
    int j=nums.length-1;

    while(i<=j){
        // Sorted (sub)array. We just return its first element.
        if(nums[i]<=nums[j])
            return nums[i];

        int m=(i+j)/2;

        if(nums[m]>=nums[i]){
            i=m+1; // The pivot is in the right subarray. So we go right
        }else{
            j=m; // m is the index of the pivot. Why don't we just return it?
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

I see the following three options:

- The (sub)array is sorted. We just return its first element.
- The pivot is in the right subarray. So we go right.
- `m` is the index of the pivot. So why don't we return it?

Comment: What do you mean by "pivot", and why do you think that `m` is its index?

Comment: The pivot is the element around which the array is rotated.  I think `m` is the index of the pivot because the pivot can be `m` or an element to the right  of `m`.

Comment: Why can't it be to the left?

Comment: Because it's already handled in `if(nums[i]<=nums[j])`

Comment: Take another look at that comparison. `m` isn't involved there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case you described `nums[m]` is not necessarily the minimum element.

For example, if the array is `[6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, during the first iteration we've got:

`i = 0`, `j = 6`, `m = 3`. `nums[m] = 2`, which is less than `nums[i]`, but it's clearly not the minimum.

Comment: Thanks, I just forgot about the case when the pivot is to the left of `m`